# Expected Length of Maximum Decreasing Subsequences in Random Sequences

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

Given $ n $ distinct numbers that are randomly shuffled to form a sequence $ A = [a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n] $, we select the largest number $ x_1 $ from the sequence. Subsequently, we pick the largest remaining number $ x_2 $ that appears after $ x_1 $, and continue this process. This results in a decreasing sequence $ X = [x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k] $ of length $ k $. What is the expected value of $ k $?

For example:

1. If the sequence $ A $ is $ [1, 5, 4, 2, 3] $, then $ X = [5, 4, 3] $.
2. If $ A = [4, 3, 2, 1, 5] $, then $ X = [5] $.
3. If $ A = [5, 1, 3, 2, 4] $, then $ X = [5, 4] $.
4. If $ A = [3, 2, 4, 5, 1] $, then $ X = [5, 1] $.

**Note: it's different from longest decreasing subsequence. For longest decreasing subsequence, the expected length is approximately $2\sqrt{n}$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Length_bounds)**

Let $ k $ be the length of $ X $, and let $ b_i = n - \text{index}(x_{k-i}) $, where $\text{index}(x_{k-i})$ denotes the position of the element $ x_{k-i} $ in $ A $.

For example, if $ A = [1, 5, 4, 2, 3] $, then $ X = [5, 4, 3] $, and:

1. $ b_0 = n - \text{index}(x_3) = n - \text{index}(3) = 5 - 5 = 0 $
2. $ b_1 = n - \text{index}(x_2) = n - \text{index}(4) = 5 - 3 = 2 $
3. $ b_2 = n - \text{index}(x_1) = n - \text{index}(5) = 5 - 2 = 3 $

The probability of the length $ k $ can be represented as
$$
P(\text{length} = k) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{{1 \le b_1 < b_2 < \cdots < b_{k-1} \le n-1}} \frac{1}{b_1 \cdot b_2 \cdots b_{k-1}}.
$$
The expected length is then
$$
E[\text{length}] = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot P(\text{length} = k).
$$

**How can we simplify the above formulas and determine their asymptotic behavior as $ n \to \infty $?**

This question arises in the context of analyzing the average space complexity of the sliding window maximum with window size $n$ for a random infinite data stream. A monotonic deque is used to track the above structure within a window of size $ n $.

For example, data stream  4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 10, and window size n = 4

[4, 3, 5, 3] 2, 4, 1, 10
deque=[5, 3]
4, [3, 5, 3, 2], 4, 1, 10
deque=[5, 3, 2]
4, 3, [5, 3, 2, 4], 1, 10
deque=[5, 4]
4, 3, 5, [3, 2, 4, 1], 10
deque=[4, 1]
4, 3, 5, 3, [2, 4, 1, 10]
deque=[10]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use $K_n$ for the length of the generated sequence $X$, when you start with $n$ shuffled distinct numbers.

Then you start with the trivial $\mathbb E[K_0]=0$ and $\mathbb E[K_1]=1$.

If the largest value in $A$ is at position $a$ then the rest of the analysis is on the right-hand $n-a$ values of $A$, so you can find the conditional expectation  $\mathbb E[K_n \mid \arg\! \max A = a] = 1 + \mathbb E[K_{n-a}]$,

which combined with shuffling giving a uniform distribution, i.e. $\mathbb P(\arg\! \max A =a)=\frac1n$, gives the recurrence $$\mathbb E[K_n] =\sum\limits_{a=1}^n \frac1n (1 + \mathbb E[K_{n-a}])$$
and experimenting with small values suggests a solution using [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) which you can easily prove by induction $$\mathbb E[K_n] =\sum\limits_{a=1}^n \frac1n = H_n$$
and, as $n$ grows, this is about $\log_e(n)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}$, so  the asymptotic behaviour is logarithmic.

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much!